# running phpspec from windows CMD creates the spec and src folders in vendor/bin instead of the project root

Tags: php, phpspec

Lately I've been learning about phpspec and gulp and decided to integrate them in my workflow.
When I installed phpspec via composer, I get the file structure of:

- vendor

  - bin

    - phpspec

there are more files but and folders but these are the relevant.

In my CMD I'm currently pointing the root of my project and trying to run:

```
vendor/bin/phpspec
```

However, I get an error saying `'vendor' isn't recognizes as internal or external command...`
so I moved into my bin folder by doing `cd vendor/bin` and then run `phpspec` and it indeed works. However, when I try to describe a class `phpspec describe SeatsHandler` it creates my files not in the root directory it creates them inside the `vendor/bin` folder:

- vendor

  - bin

    - phpspec
    - spec
    - src

I tried to see how I can configure that and read about `phpspec.yml`. I've created such file along with `app` directory in my main folder (would love to get rid of app directory):

```
    suites:
      app_suite:
        src_path: app
```

I tried putting this file in my main directory, but it didn't work, I got the same result as before. I also tried moving this file into `vendor/bin` but no avail.

How can I make phpspec create the files in my root directory instead of inside `vendor/bin`? Also, why does it ignore the `phpspec.yml`?

### EDIT:

I managed to make it work by modifying my `phpspec.yml` into:

```
    suites:
      app_suite:
        src_path: ../../src/
        spec_path: ../../
```

And put it in `vendor/bin`. However, a question still remains, how can I run phpspec without going inside the `vendor/bin` directory in CMD?

Answer (score 1):

in your composer.json file, just add the `"bin-dir": "bin"` under `config` like so:

```
{
"require-dev": {
    "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.0"
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"autoload": {"psr-0": {"": "bin/src"}}
}
```

and youll get a `bin` folder on your root directory along with the `vendor` directory.

- bin
- vendor

then you can run phpspec on your root directory exactly as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can install it globally as following;

```
composer global require phpspec/phpspec
```

now you can call it phpspec